# getting maximum number of occurrences along with count in group by

Tags: mysql

I have a table which looks like this

```
question_id   response
 1              yes
 1              yes
 2              agree
 1              no
 3              disagree
 2              agree
 2              disagree
```

I want my query to return

```
question_id      max_response     max_response_count   total_responses
1                yes              2                    3
2                agree            2                    3
3                disagree         1                    1
```

The query

```
SELECT question_id,
       max(response),
       count(max(response)),
       count(*)
FROM response
GROUP BY question_id
```

gives `Invalid use of group function` error.

Which query should I place to get the above output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT T.question_id,Max(MR) max_response,MAX(CR)max_response_count,(Select Count(question_id) from response where question_id = T.question_id)total_responses
FROM 
  (SELECT question_id,max(response) MR,count(response) CR
   FROM response group by question_id,response
   )T 
GROUP BY T.question_id
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d7a1/37)**

**OP:**

```
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |QUESTION_ID  | MAX_RESPONSE   | MAX_RESPONSE_COUNT |TOTAL_RESPONSES |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |  1          |    yes         |        2           |       3        |
    |  2          |    disagree    |        2           |       3        |
    |  3          |    disagree    |        1           |       1        |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my query by looking your sqlfiddle data. please try now:

```
create table tableA(question_id int,response varchar(50));

insert into tableA values(1,'yes'),(1,'yes'),(2,'agree'),(1,'no'),(3,'disagree'),(2,'agree'),(2,'disagree');

SELECT question_id,
       max(response) AS max_response,
(select count(response) from tableA b where a.response= b.response and a.question_id= b.question_id ) as max_response_count,
       count(*) AS count_response

FROM tableA a
GROUP BY question_id
```

I tried and get the result as expected..

Comment: I have updated the query please test now..Dont forget to upvote if works for you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) AS total_responses ,
       question_id ,
       count(max(response)) AS max_response_count
FROM response
GROUP BY question_id ,
         response
```

Comment: It has error as `Invalid use of group function: ` .Please check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d7a1/38